# how to get current test method name in any class of project in codedUI?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, coded-ui-tests, testcontext

I want to compare the current test method name, but getting an exception that
TestContext returns null.

```
public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

private void SetTaxCode(Bene beneDetails)
{if (TestContext.TestName.Contains("NegativeTest"))
{SetBenecode(TestDataProvider.TestDataProvider.InValidBeneficiaryTaxCode);
}
else
SetBenecode(beneDetails.BeneficiaryTaxCode);
}
```

TestContext.TestName returns correct test name in the basic.cs, but I can't inherit basic.cs to the new class, how can I then use TestContext in different classes?

Answer (score 0):

You could make your `TestContext` property [static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members). That way, you will be able to call it even without instantiating the basic.cs class.

If basic.cs is not accessible to other classes, you could make a static class and put your `TestContext` property there.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know from experience with CodedUI, `TestContext` cannot be made static. It's must be non-static by definition.
If you want to use `TestContext` in different classes you can pass it in as a parameter similar to the following:

```
[CodedUITest]
    public class SomeCodedUITest1
    {    
            public TestContext TestContext
            {
                get
                {
                    return testContextInstance;
                }
                set
                {
                    testContextInstance = value;
                }
            }
            private TestContext testContextInstance;

        [TestCategory("DataFiles"),
                 DataSource ( .... )]
          public void SampleMethod()
            {
                MyClass = new MyClass(TestContext);
            }
    }
```

Then inside `MyClass` class just use constructor

```
public MyClass (TestContext testContext)
  {
  }
```

You can then use `TestContext` data inside `MyClass`. For example, `testContext.DataConnection.Database`.